# businesslogic in mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, projects-and-solutions, business-logic

I have businesslogic in an MVVM application - not really "data" but real logic, which mean "rules". Example: Dragging items inside a wpf TreeView, where each object is based on a viewmodel and has properties that depend upon business cases.
Sure, these properties in the viewmodel are "business-specific".
But I tend to not put a static, like "CanAcceptDragObject()", under "viewmodel" or "Model". What 's the common local place for such general (mostly static), business-specific code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having a hard time understanding your overall question but to answer your specific question, "where do I put business logic?"  The answer, in most cases is the Model.

Comment: I understand that in MVVM, you would have something like a person name / address / age database keep in the model, which feeds a Person-viewmodel.

Comment: In my wpf treeview, the items represent business-specific objects, example: "empty box", "box of 5 apples", "full apple box". The decision if an item can be dragged / dropped or accept other dragged items, is made in a "Rules" class (example businesslogic: 10 apples = full box"). As I understand you (and mvvm) the drag and drop rules would be a "model" of the business rules, and so put under "model". What Do You think ?

Comment: For me, the VM is only a means of translating from view to model.  The model handles most logic related to whatever outcome you want expressed as a result of user input.  The view can contain "logic" if that logic is merely a way of representing something to the user which has no bearing on the true outcome (ie ValueConverters, Text styles etc etc)

Comment: I agree. the viewmodel should be the interface between both. And Business-rules (which lead to a specific drag & drop behaviour) are part of the applications model!